# How do I make onkeyup only be an alphabet key?

Tags: javascript, ascii, dom-events

I'm making a letter guessing game and I want the `onkeyup` to only accept alphabet keys.

```
document.onkeyup = function (event) {
  var userGuess = event.key;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to get the `keycode` from the `which`-property of the `event` and translate it to a `char`. Then you can test the char with regex.

```js
document.addEventListener('keyup', function (event) {
  let char = String.fromCharCode(event.which);
  if (/[a-z]/i.test(char)) {
    // Do something
    console.log(char);
  }
});
```

```html
Press any key!
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the ASCII code:

```
if (event.keyCode >= 65 && event.keyCode <= 90) {
    console.log("input was a-z");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since keyCode is being deprecated, a slightly more modern approach could be something like this...

```
window.addEventListener('keyup', event => {
    if (event.key >= 'a' && event.key <= 'z') {
        // do something
    }
}
```